# SQL - Query to display average as either "longer than" or "shorter than"

Tags: sql

Here are the tables I've created:

```
CREATE TABLE Plane_new (Pnum char(3), Feature varchar2(20), Ptype varchar2(15), 
primary key (Pnum));

CREATE TABLE Employee_new (eid char(3), ename varchar(10), salary number(7,2), mid char(3),
PRIMARY KEY (eid), FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES Employee_new);

CREATE TABLE Pilot_new (eid char(3), Licence char(9), primary key (eid), 
foreign key (eid) references Employee_new on delete cascade);

CREATE TABLE FlightI_new (Fnum char(4), Fdate date, Duration number(2), Pid char(3), 
Pnum char(3), primary key (Fnum), foreign key (Pid) references Pilot_new (eid), 
foreign key (Pnum) references Plane_new);
```

And here is the query I must complete:
For each flight, display its number, the name of the pilot who implemented the flight 
and the words ‘Longer than average’ if the flight duration was longer than average or 
the words ‘Shorter than average’ if the flight duration was shorter than or equal to the 
average.  For the column holding the words ‘Longer than average’ or ‘Shorter than average’ 
make a header Length.

Here is what I've come up with - with no luck!

```
SELECT F.Fnum, E.ename,
CASE Length 
WHEN F.Duration>(SELECT AVG(F.Duration) FROM FlightI_new F)
THEN "Longer than average"
WHEN F.Duration<=(SELECT AVG(F.Duration) FROM FlightI_new F)
THEN 'Shorter than average' END
FROM FlightI_new F LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_new E ON F.Pid=E.eid
GROUP BY F.Fnum, E.ename;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you try the query provided and let us know if you still face an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F.Fnum, E.ename,
(CASE F.Duration 
WHEN F.Duration>(SELECT AVG(B.Duration) FROM FlightI_new B)
THEN 'Longer than average'
ELSE 'Shorter than average' END) AS LENGTH
FROM FlightI_new F LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_new E ON F.Pid=E.eid
GROUP BY F.Fnum, E.ename;
```

Comment: Still giving me an error of "missing keyword" at line 3 - the star showing up right under the ">" sign

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
THEN "Longer than average"
```

with this line:

```
THEN 'Longer than average'
```

In other words, change the double quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please take a look at this sample query in * [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03289/4)
Perhaps it was more or less a syntax issue. You use `Case Length` instead of using `As Length` at the end of the Case statement. I haven't done any changes to your query in terms of optimizing though.

```
SELECT F.Fnum, E.ename,
CASE 
WHEN F.Duration>(SELECT AVG(F.Duration) 
                 FROM FlightI_new F)
THEN Longer than average
WHEN F.Duration<=(SELECT AVG(F.Duration) 
                  FROM FlightI_new F)
THEN 'Shorter than average' 
END as Length
FROM FlightI_new F 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee_new E 
ON F.FPid=E.eid
```

Provides the following results as per the sample data I have used. I am still not sure if your 'mid' column , `FOREIGN KEY (mid) REFERENCES Employee_new);` is really referencing to anywhere...So I removed the referential integrity and left it alone.

```
FNUM    ENAME   LENGTH
f001    kaen    Longer than average
f002    jerry   Longer than average
f003    dane    Longer than average
f004    jerry   Shorter than average
f005    kaen    Shorter than average
f006    tim     Shorter than average
f007    dane    Shorter than average
```